# flutter how to fix null error and how to allow a model can be null

Tags: flutter, model, null, dart-null-safety

[image]

Hi so I am having a problem of null things...

how can i prevent this kind of error

```
 class CheckupAppointment {
  int id;
  int userId;
  int companion;
  String dates;
  String times;
  String hairColor;
  String companionRegisteredType = '';
  String companionRegisteredNumber = '';

  CheckupAppointment(
    this.id,
    this.userId,
    this.companion,
    this.dates,
    this.times,
    this.hairColor,
    this.companionRegisteredType,
    this.companionRegisteredNumber,
  );

  CheckupAppointment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'] ?? '';
    userId = json['user_id'] ?? '';
    companion = json['companion_id'] ?? '';
    dates = json['reserved_at'].split('T').first ?? '';
    times = json['time'] ?? '';
    hairColor = json['hair_color'] ?? '';
    companionRegisteredType = json['registered_type'] ?? '';
    companionRegisteredNumber = json['registered_number'] ?? '';
  }
}
```

So i hope this model can also contains null.
now our flutter version 2.2.3 and... we can't upgrade our flutter version at the moment

so what should i do if i would like to make this model contains null or can be null

Comment: The code you've shown isn't relevant.  You're accessing the `dates` member of some variable of type `CheckupAppointment?` that is null.  Where are you accessing the `dates` member?  In general, to avoid this kind of error, check if the variable is `null` before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this model.

```
class CheckupAppointment {
  CheckupAppointment({
    this.id,
    this.userId,
    this.companion,
    this.dates,
    this.times,
    this.hairColor,
    this.companionRegisteredType,
    this.companionRegisteredNumber,
  });

  int? id;
  int? userId;
  int? companion;
  String? dates;
  String? times;
  String? hairColor;
  String? companionRegisteredType;
  String? companionRegisteredNumber;

  factory CheckupAppointment.fromRawJson(String str) => CheckupAppointment.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory CheckupAppointment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CheckupAppointment(
    id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    userId: json["user_id"] == null ? null : json["user_id"],
    companion: json["companion_id"] == null ? null : json["companion_id"],
    dates: json["reserved_at"] == null ? null : json['reserved_at'].split('T').first,
    times: json["times"] == null ? null : json["times"],
    hairColor: json["hair_color"] == null ? null : json["hair_color"],
    companionRegisteredType: json["registered_type "] == null ? null : json["registered_type "],
    companionRegisteredNumber: json["registered_number "] == null ? null : json["registered_number "],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id == null ? null : id,
    "user_id": userId == null ? null : userId,
    "companion_id": companion == null ? null : companion,
    "reserved_at": dates == null ? null : dates,
    "times": times == null ? null : times,
    "hair_color": hairColor == null ? null : hairColor,
    "registered_type ": companionRegisteredType == null ? null : companionRegisteredType,
    "registered_number ": companionRegisteredNumber == null ? null : companionRegisteredNumber,
  };
}
```